# Calculating the values of a generalization of binomials to permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, permutations, enumerative-combinatorics

let $$\Pi\binom{n}{k}:=\mathrm{card}\left( \left\lbrace \lbrace \Pi_1^n\,\cdots\,\Pi_k^n\rbrace\,|\,0\leq \pi_{r,c}\in\sum_{i=1}^k\Pi_i^n\ni\pi_{r,c}\leq 1\right\rbrace\right)$$ be the number of sets with $k\leq n$ distinct $n\times n$ permutation matrices *without* common non-zero entry.

> **Questions:**
>
> - has that number already appeared in publications and if yes,
>
>   - what name and/or notation was used?
> - can $\Pi\binom{n}{k}$ be expressed via standard functions of $n$ and $k$?
> - what is the time complexity of calculating $\Pi\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: It is a $k\times n$ Latin rectangle.  See this paper for a nice summary of theoretical and practical methods: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-the-number-of-latin-rectangles/E093CA0EC0A723261F4D635AED40A567

Comment: @BrendanMcKay your comment would be an acceptable answer to me. My question was essentially motivated by counting regular graphs by interpreting them as sums of these collections of permutation matrices. The relation to Latin rectangles seems interesting to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a $k\times n$ latin rectangle: write the permutations one per row.

[This paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-the-australian-mathematical-society/article/on-the-number-of-latin-rectangles/E093CA0EC0A723261F4D635AED40A567) has a nice summary of theoretical and practical methods.

The sum of the permutation matrices can be interpreted as the adjacency matrix of a regular digraph or the biadjacency matrix of a regular bipartite graph. However each digraph/graph can be decomposed into permutation matrices in a varying number of ways, so there is no precise relationship between the counts.